# sql select row if any one row of group by does not contain value

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

How do I select a row only if group by does not contain a value.

Sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tbl (
    id serial NOT NULL ,
    product int4 NULL,
    family int4 NULL    
);

insert into tbl values 
(1,3,200),
(2,6,201),
(3,7,201),
(4,1,203),
(5,3,204),
(6,6,205),
(7,1,206);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/744bc1/2

Find all products such that:

1. product != 6
2. does not belong to any family,

   - if one of the family has product 6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use correlated subquery with `not exists`

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/744bc1/3)**

```
select product , family
from tbl a 
  where not exists ( select 1 from tbl b where a.family=b.family and product=6)
```